# Snake game with turtle module: How to stop it from changing direction too fast

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

As a part of a Python beginner course, I just finished coding the classic Snake game with the turtle module. I have noticed a problem which is not addressed in the course's solution code, so I wanted to ask here for a possible solution.

I've created a class named snake, which creates segments of the snake (squares) as turtle objects. The first square sets the direction and the other segments follow. This is the method that makes the snake move (self.head is set to the item in the list of segments with index 0):

```
def move(self):
    for segment_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):
        new_x = self.segments[segment_num - 1].xcor()
        new_y = self.segments[segment_num - 1].ycor()
        self.segments[segment_num].goto(new_x, new_y)
    self.head.forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

The arrow keys trigger the following methods, which change direction and are supposed to prevent the snake to move back on itself:

```
def up(self):
    if self.head.heading() != DOWN:
        self.head.setheading(UP)

def down(self):
    if self.head.heading() != UP:
        self.head.setheading(DOWN)

def left(self):
    if self.head.heading() != RIGHT:
        self.head.setheading(LEFT)

def right(self):
    if self.head.heading() != LEFT:
        self.head.setheading(RIGHT)
```

Now the problem is that if the user presses two arrow keys very quickly (e.g. up and left when snake is going right), the direction is changed before the program has a chance to make the move forward in between. This allows the snake to move back on itself and leads to a game over.

I've tried to have it move forward every time it changes direction, like this:

```
def left(self):
    if self.head.heading() != RIGHT:
        self.head.setheading(LEFT)
        self.head.forward(20)
```

This does seem to solve the problem but creates another one - the last segment of the snake now is not 'perfectly attached' anymore for a moment when changing direction, but one position off diagonally.

Does anyone know of a good solution for this? I'll be happy to post more of the code that I've written for this game, if relevant.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you uploaded your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure that everything stays synchronized could be to add a "movements queue" to store the user commands.
You'd have 2 tasks, one for user input and the other for snake processing, and it would be a producer-consumer problem.
*Once you upload your code I can update my answer with an example*

Answer (score 0):

You have a `time.sleep()` call in your main game loop, right?

For example:

```
delay = 0.1
while True:
    time.sleep(delay)
    # Your game code
```

Well, you can put that into the turn functions:

```
def up(self):
    if self.head.heading() != DOWN:
        time.sleep(delay)
        self.head.setheading(UP)

def down(self):
    if self.head.heading() != UP:
        time.sleep(delay)
        self.head.setheading(DOWN)

def left(self):
    if self.head.heading() != RIGHT:
        time.sleep(delay)
        self.head.setheading(LEFT)

def right(self):
    if self.head.heading() != LEFT:
        time.sleep(delay)
        self.head.setheading(RIGHT)
```